# Retrieve closest value from another dataframe in pandas for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have an air quality dataframe for my location that looks like this:

| idx | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | air | Good |
| 1 | co | 181.91 |
| 2 | no | 4.58 |
| 3 | no2 | 11.48 |
| 4 | o3 | 33.62 |
| 5 | so2 | 0.22 |
| 6 | nh3 | 5.45 |
| 7 | pm2_5 | 6.13 |
| 8 | pm10 | 8.99 |

I have another dataframe with thresholds for some of these components (values are the upper boundary)

| idx | type | Good | Fair | Moderate | Poor | Very Poor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | no2 | 50 | 100 | 200 | 400 | 401 |
| 1 | pm10 | 25 | 50 | 90 | 180 | 181 |
| 2 | o3 | 60 | 120 | 180 | 240 | 241 |
| 3 | pm2_5 | 15 | 30 | 55 | 110 | 111 |

I would like to add a new column to the air quality dataframe that would tell me if the current value is "Good","Fair","Moderate", etc. but I am struggling at how to better approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is unclear, but the two key steps you need are [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to reshape the DataFrame of scores and [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=pa) to merge by closest value:

```
(pd
 .merge_asof(df1.assign(New=pd.to_numeric(df1['Value'], errors='coerce'))
                .fillna(0).sort_values(by='New'),
             df2.melt('type', value_name='New', var_name='Score')
                .astype({'New': float})
                .sort_values(by='New'),
             left_by='Type', right_by='type', on='New',
             direction='forward',
            )         
)
```

Once you have this, you can rework the columns, fill the NaNs, etc.

output:

```
    Type   Value     New   type Score
0    air    Good    0.00    NaN   NaN
1    so2    0.22    0.22    NaN   NaN
2     no    4.58    4.58    NaN   NaN
3    nh3    5.45    5.45    NaN   NaN
4  pm2_5    6.13    6.13  pm2_5  Good
5   pm10    8.99    8.99   pm10  Good
6    no2   11.48   11.48    no2  Good
7     o3   33.62   33.62     o3  Good
8     co  181.91  181.91    NaN   NaN
```